# Create new column that is the sum of one column by date and one other column

Tags: python, pandas, sum, pandas-groupby

I am trying to total figures in the 'Amount' column by date and where the class is the same.

E.g. of desired df is below where i am trying to calculate 'Total Amount' column:

---

> - To Date        Name    Class   Amount  Total Amount
> - 1/31/2020  Smith   A          1    5
> - 1/31/2020  Byrne   A          1    5
> - 1/31/2020  McDaid  A          1    5
> - 1/31/2020  Buba    A          1    5
> - 1/31/2020  Holland A          1    5
> - 1/31/2020  Capital B          1    2
> - 1/31/2020  Padmir  B          1    2

I have tried the below but its giving me an output of NA

```
df['Total Amount'] = df.groupby('To Date' and 'Class')['Amount'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to provide grouped columns as a list:

```
df_totals = df.groupby(['To Date', 'Class'])['Amount'].sum()
```

Note this will return a dataframe of different dimension.  If you want to add a new row with the value to the original, you can use:

```
df["Total Amount"] = df.groupby(['To Date', 'Class'])['Amount'].transform(sum)
```